# Use of SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

Here in below code we can show difference between `Select` and `SelectMany` operator.

Is there any way to avoid the common skills? For example if two employees have the C# skill then I want to print them only once.

```
namespace LinqOperators
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            Employee emp1 = new Employee { Name = "Deepak", Skills = new List<string> { "C", "C++", "Java" } };//Adding Skills List to Employee List i.e List of List
            Employee emp2 = new Employee { Name = "Karan", Skills = new List<string> { "SQL Server", "C#", "ASP.NET" } };

            Employee emp3 = new Employee { Name = "Lalit", Skills = new List<string> { "C#", "ASP.NET MVC", "Windows Azure", "SQL Server" } };

            employees.Add(emp1);
            employees.Add(emp2);
            employees.Add(emp3);

            // Query using Select()
            IEnumerable<List<String>> resultSelect = employees.Select(e => e.Skills);

            Console.WriteLine("**************** Select ******************");

            // Two foreach loops are required to iterate through the results
            // because the query returns a collection of arrays.
            foreach (List<String> skillList in resultSelect)
            {
                foreach (string skill in skillList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(skill);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();//To differntiate Two Skill Lists
            }

            // Query using SelectMany()
            IEnumerable<string> resultSelectMany = employees.SelectMany(emp => emp.Skills);

            Console.WriteLine("**************** SelectMany ******************");

            // Only one foreach loop is required to iterate through the results 
            // since query returns a one-dimensional collection.
            foreach (string skill in resultSelectMany)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(skill);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`SelectMany` will flatten your `IEnumerable` such that it won't produce `IEnumerable of IEnumerables` but `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> skills; //not this [[C#, Java], [C, C++, Java, C#]]
IEnumerable<string> skills; //but this [C#, Java, C, C++, Java, C#]
```

You could use `Distinct` in your `resultSelectMany` to get common skill only once.

```
resultSelectMany = resultSelectMany.Distinct(); //[C#, Java, C, C++]
```

Or to put it in the same line:

```
// Query using SelectMany()
IEnumerable<string> resultSelectMany = employees.SelectMany(emp => emp.Skills).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) to remove duplicates

Comment: Ironically there are 3 identical answers, all to use Distinct()

Comment: I was going to toss around the idea of using a `Set<T>` to possibly get some kind of performance enhancement. Luckily for me, I checked `Distinct()`'s implementation beforehand. *Shockingly*, it uses a `Set`.  ;)